# Optimizing Select SQL request with millions of entries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a table counting around 40,000,000 rows, and I'm trying to extract first entry for each "subscription_id" (foreign key from another table), here is my acutal request:

```
SELECT * FROM billing bill WHERE bill.billing_value not like 'not_ok%' 
AND
   (SELECT bill2.billing_id
      FROM billing bill2
      WHERE bill2.subscription_id = bill.subscription_id 
      ORDER BY bill2.billing_id ASC LIMIT 1
    )= bill.billing_id;
```

This request is working correctly, when I put a small limit on it, but I cannot seem to process it for all the database.

Is there a way I could optimise it somehow ? Or do things in an other way ?

Table indexes and structure:
[image: Structure]

Indexes:
[image: Indexes]

Comment: Show your table structure and indexes please

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER() in CTE for selecting the earliest (?) row per group.

Comment: Remove order by and limit...add min(billing_id)

Comment: Have yo tried making an execution plan? That should help you identify the problem.

Comment: @Martin, I estimate the table would still be under 2GB even with 40 million rows, so I wouldn't go directly to sharding as a solution. Indexes and caching should be able to handle this.

Comment: You can't simply change the LIMIT -- it will give an error.  Perhaps you changed `=` to `IN`?  In any case, please show us the query you are asking about.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Neither IN, nor ROW_NUMBER is likely to be the fastest way.  Please provide the version number of MySQL; there have been multiple changes in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, because I don't have an MySQL DB at hand, but this query seems much simpler:

```
select * 
from   billing
where  billing_id in (select min(billing_id)
                      from   billing
                      group by subscription_id)
and    billing_value not like 'not_ok%';
```

The inner select get the minimum billing_id for all subscriptions. The outer gets the rest of the billing record.

If performance is an issue, I'd add the billing_id field in the third index, so you get an **index with (subscription_id,billing_id)**. This will help for the inner query.

Comment: You would also need the same `not like` condition inside the subquery, or else it could produce billing_id values that don't match any row of the outer query.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think the original query does the same... If the smallest billing_id has a value like 'not_ok%', no record will be shown for that subscription. I think...

Comment: You're right, the same would happen in the original query, but I'd assume that's a bug, because it doesn't match the OP's verbal description of the task: "first entry for each subscription_id." The bug would cause some subscriptions to be mysteriously left out of the result.

Comment: OP doesn't say anything in the description about the "not like", but the question does mention that the query is working correctly.

Comment: Perhaps it's working correctly in their current data by coincidence, because they don't have any cases currently where the first row for any given subscription would be excluded by that condition. At least, not yet.

Comment: You are right Bill Karwin, its a bug, the original desire is to get the smalest billing_id entry not beeing like "not_ok%" for each subscription_id. I'll try both mentioned solutions as soon as I got access to my database and update the topic.

Comment: This worked like a charm, adding the not like inside the subquery as Bill Karwin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the ROW_NUMBER() solution mentioned in the comments above.

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by subscription_id order by billing_id) as rownum
  from billing 
  where billing_value not like 'not_ok%'
) t
where rownum = 1;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function is available in MySQL 8.0, so if you haven't upgraded yet, you must do so to use this function.

Unfortunately, this won't be much of an improvement, because the `NOT LIKE` causes a table-scan regardless of the pattern you search for.

I believe it requires a virtual column with an index to optimize that condition:

```
alter table billing 
 add column ok as tinyint(1) as (billing_value not like 'not_ok%'),
 add index (ok);

select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by subscription_id order by billing_id) as rownum
  from billing 
  where ok = true
) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Now it will use the index on the `ok` virtual column to reduce the set of examined rows.

This still might be a costly query on a 40 million row table, because the derived table subquery creates a large temporary table. If it's not fast enough, you'll have to really reconsider how you store and query this data.

For example, adding a column `first_ok` with an index, which is true only on the rows you need to fetch (the first row per subscriber_id without 'not_ok' as the billing value). But you must maintain this new column manually, and risk it being wrong if you don't do that. This is a denormalized design, but tailored to the query you want to run.